Вызвать в конструкторе класса родительский конструктор
Написал иерархию классов, а именно Weapon ->StrengthWeapon, CountableWeapon ->Bow. Как правильно вызывать в конструкторе Bow конструкторы родительских классов?
from hos_stats import Points

class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name: str, level: int, damage: int):
        self._name = name
        self._level = level
        self._damage = damage

class StrengthWeapon(Weapon.Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name: str, level: int, damage: int, strength: int):
        super().__init__(name, level, damage)
        self._strength = Points.Points(strength, strength)

class CountableWeapon(Weapon.Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name: str, level: int, damage: int, count: int):
        super().__init__(name, level, damage)
        self._count = Points.Points(count, count)

class Bow(StrengthWeapon.StrengthWeapon, CountableWeapon.CountableWeapon):
    LEVEL_DAMAGE = (5,)
    LEVEL_STRENGTH = (35,)
    LEVEL_COUNT = (12,)

    def __init__(self, name: str, level: int):
        damage = self.LEVEL_DAMAGE[level - 1]
        strength = Points.Points(self.LEVEL_STRENGTH[level - 1], self.LEVEL_STRENGTH[level - 1])
        count = Points.Points(self.LEVEL_COUNT[level - 1], self.LEVEL_COUNT[level - 1])

        super().__init__(name, level, damage, strength)
        super(CountableWeapon.CountableWeapon).__init__(self, name, level, damage, count)


bow = Bow('My bow', 1)

# Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "d:\Python\Heart of Sword\main.py", line 32, in <module>
#   Bow.Bow('Emerald Bow', 1)
# File "d:\Python\Heart of Sword\hos_weapons\Bow.py", line 18, in __init__
#   super().__init__(name, level, damage, strength)
# File "d:\Python\Heart of Sword\hos_weapons\StrengthWeapon.py", line 9, in __init__
#   super().__init__(name, level, damage)
# TypeError: CountableWeapon.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'count'


Могу предложить 2 варианта:
1) Через super()
class Weapon():
    def __init__(self, name, level, damage, **kwargs):
        # super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Weapon", ": ", name, ": ", level, ": ", damage)

class StrengthWeapon(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name: str, level: int, damage: int,  strength: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, level, damage, **kwargs)
        print("StrengthWeapon", ": ", name, ": ", level, ": ", damage, ": ",  strength)

class CountableWeapon(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name: str, level: int, damage: int,  count: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, level, damage, **kwargs)
        print("CountableWeapon", ": ", name, ": ", level, ": ", damage, ": ",  count)

class Bow(StrengthWeapon, CountableWeapon):
    def __init__(self, name, level):
        kwargs = {
            "damage" : 100,
            "count" : (16, 24),
            "strength" : (12, 6),
        }
        super().__init__( name, level, **kwargs)
        # super().__init__(name, level, damage=100, count=(16, 24), strength=(12, 6))
        print("Bow", ": ", name, ": ", level)
        
Bow('My bow', 1)


Вывод:
Weapon :  My bow :  1 :  100
CountableWeapon :  My bow :  1 :  100 :  (16, 24)
StrengthWeapon :  My bow :  1 :  100 :  (12, 6)
Bow :  My bow :  1

2) Явно указывать классы
class Weapon():
    def __init__(self, name, level, damage):
        print("Weapon", ": ", name, ": ", level, ": ", damage)
        

class StrengthWeapon(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name, level, damage, strength):
        print("StrengthWeapon", ": ", name, ": ", level, ": ", damage, ": ",  strength)
        Weapon.__init__(self, name, level, damage)
        

class CountableWeapon(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name, level, damage, count):
        print("StrengthWeapon", ": ", name, ": ", level, ": ", damage, ": ",  count)
        Weapon.__init__(self, name, level, damage)
        

class Bow(StrengthWeapon, CountableWeapon):
    def __init__(self, name, level):
        print("Bow", ": ", name, ": ", level)
        damage = 100
        count= (16, 24)
        strength = (12, 6)
        StrengthWeapon.__init__(self, name, level, damage, strength)
        CountableWeapon.__init__(self, name, level, damage, count)

Bow('My bow', 1)

Вывод:
Bow :  My bow :  1
StrengthWeapon :  My bow :  1 :  100 :  (12, 6)
Weapon :  My bow :  1 :  100
StrengthWeapon :  My bow :  1 :  100 :  (16, 24)
Weapon :  My bow :  1 :  100

Оба варианта работают, но если делать через super() то он позаботится о том, что бы не вызывать Weapon дважды. Так же если что-то в коде поменяется, то не нужно будет править явные вызовы.

Я тестил через отладчик. Сначала вызывается инициализатор класса Bow. Он инициализирует переменные damage, strength и count. Затем идет переход к инициализатору класса StrengthWeapon через функцию super(). Внутри инициализатора StrengthWeapon вызывается функция super(), которая должна создать временный объект класса Weapon. Но в итоге интерпретатор выходит из инициализатора StrengthWeapon и вылетает ошибка, что в инициализаторе CountableWeapon отсутствует позиционный аргумент count, хотя до него интерпретатор еще не дошел. Не совсем понимаю работу функции super()

Всё логично же: когда вы вызываете super().init() в классе Bow, питон пытается вызвать _ _ init_ _ обоих родительских классов отсюда и ошибка. Вы можете сделать так, чтобы класс Bow наследовал только от одного класса или использовать показанные подходы из моего ответа.

А я написал вот так:
super().init(name, level, damage, strength)
super(StrengthWeapon, self).init(name, level, damage, count)
Является ли это правильным, поскольку создаются два объекта класса Weapon?

Я просто пробую разные варианты, чтобы понять логику работы Пайтон

По-моему вместо super().__init__(...) можно просто super(...) вызывать.

@CrazyElf, такое не работает. Аргументом super может быть тип (класс), для уточнения, от какого класса нужно метод вызвать (при множественном наследовании, например), но super() не работает как сокращенная запись super().__init__(...)

@insolor Хм, значит ложная память. Странно, мне казалось, что было как-то проще всё.
